# Temporal Data Management in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, temporal-database, bi-temporal, nosql

Is there an api (like hibernate, etc) to manage temporal data in Google Cloud Datastore? 
Basically i need to maintain bi-temporal data in my datastore. Is there an api that i can use to easily manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "bi-temporal data".

If you mean different data classes that are have different pricing and access times, there are different storage classes (standard and nearline).  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes.  These are set at the bucket level at creation time.  For example: `gsutil mb -c nearline -l region bucket-url`.

You can also set a time-to-live at the bucket level.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

Using `gsutil` you can set this policy by uploading a JSON file like this example from the docs:

```
{
  "lifecycle": {
    "rule":
    [
      {
        "action": {"type": "Delete"},
        "condition": {"age": 365}
      }
    ]
  } 
}
```

Save to a file and then `gsutil set json-file-name bucket-url`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Justin. Let me give you an example of my use case. I maintain a product prices database in appengine datastore. I want to maintain all price changes that ever happens to any product any number of times. So how can I manage that in appengine datastore. Hope that clarifies the question

Comment: Sorry I got confused because you tagged this question [google-cloud-storage].  You should try changing your tag to [google-cloud-datastore] or you'll miss people who are experts with datastore.  (Although, I will tell you just off the cuff that your problem sounds like a much better fit for a structured SQL based database than something like datastore.  Denormalizing price data into a single document is going to suck.)